# Multiple Coin Toss in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, I am tossing four coins and counting the number of heads.  The code I am using is:

```
CoinHeads = Int(Round(Rnd(), 0)) + Int(Round(Rnd(), 0)) + Int(Round(Rnd(), 0)) + Int(Round(Rnd(), 0))
```

This works, but I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do this in Excel VBA code that would still give me the same distribution of head counts from 0 to 4.  Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Just make one call to `Rnd()`, and then segment the number of heads based on the probability. See [this answer on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1791243/145578).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted just to simplify your statements a little bit you could use `Int(2 * Rnd())` instead:

```
CoinHeads = Int(2 * Rnd()) + Int(2 * Rnd()) + Int(2 * Rnd()) + Int(2 * Rnd())
```

Other than that you can segment the number of heads like @Comintern says in their comment.

Comment: Thanks for this approach, too.  I will try both and check for execution time.  I'm doing a million iterations on the game, so this could be something to check.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a little function and pass the number of heads as parameter to generalize your code (here tossing head if the random number is larger than or equal to 0.5):

```
Public Function getNumberOfHeads(ByVal nb As Integer) As Integer
    Dim nbHeads As Integer: nbHeads = 0
    Randomize 
    For j = 0 To nb 
        If Rnd() >= 0.5 Then nbHeads = nbHeads + 1
    Next j
    getNumberOfHeads = nbHeads
End Function
```

And then you use it like this in your code:

```
numberOfHeads = getNumberOfHeads(4)
```